# What query would get me this result? JSON and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, json

```
{
    "cars": {
        "toyota": [
            {"model":"*****", "doors":"*","color":"*****"},
            {"model":"*****", "doors":"*","color":"*****"}
                  ],
        "Ford": [
            {"model":"*****", "doors":"*","color":"*****"},
            {"model":"*****", "doors":"*","color":"*****"}
        ]
    }
}
```

What query would give me the following result?

It's a JSON object (cars), that contains the multiple arrays each for a different model of car. In each array would be other types of data e.g. doors, color, years.... and more

I tried this code:

```
<?php 

require 'conn_pdo.php';

$conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$sql = "select * from test_cars where cars in (select cars from test_cars GROUP BY cars) ORDER BY RAND()";

$stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> execute();
$row = $stmt -> fetchAll();
$json['cars'] = $row;
echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

But the result is not that I hope

```
{ "cars": 
         [ {"model":"*****", "doors":*","color":*****"},  
           {"model":"*****","doors":"*","color":*****"} ,
           {"model":"*****", "doors":"*","color":*****"}, 
           {"model":"*****", "doors":"*","color":*****"},
           .......
         ] 
}
```

I got cars object, containing **one arrays** for all different model of car !!

Comment: Your db query is irrelevant, process the results in php into whatever format you want. Please show your code if you want more help

Comment: don't dump unformatted code into comments, update the question instead so everybody can read it

Comment: Can see your PHP that creates this output? I suspect you need to loop through your cars, and group by manufacturer. You can do that using `GROUP BY` in your query, or in PHP using a loop.

Comment: help with what, where did the code go? You deleted comment but didn't update question

Comment: where i can use loop in Php !!

Comment: (A couple of tips: it is best not to chase for answers in the comments - readers will answer at their leisure, and people sometimes downvote if they feel you are not being patient. Also, the code you supplied was not tested, since it was missing a `;` semi-colon, which I have now fixed. It is best to show code that you have actually been working on and that will run (even if not correctly). Anyway, I have now added an answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. I've removed the `GROUP BY` approach, since the approach in the question doesn't use it correctly - it throws the grouping away by using an `IN` query. I think it's pretty easy to do in PHP anyway.

```
// It would be good to check to ensure you have a valid connection,
// and that the prepare/execute calls are successful
$sql = "SELECT * from test_cars";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

$out = [];
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    // Let's process by brand (since you have not shown your
    // schema, you will need to adjust column names to suit)
    $brand = $row['brand'];

    // Get other data
    $model = $row['model'];
    $doors = $row['doors'];
    $colour = $row['colour'];

    // Check to ensure the brand is an array, so that we don't
    // get an error when we push
    if (!isset($out[$brand]))
    {
        $out[$brand] = [];
    }

    // Now push the data on to the end (using [])
    $out[$brand][] = [
        'model' => $model,
        'doors' => $doors,
        'colour' => $colour,
    ];
}

$json['cars'] = $out;
echo json_encode($json);
```

This is untested, but should give you the general idea. You should expect to have to adjust it a little bit, as with all answers on Stack Overflow. I've used the new array syntax (as of PHP 5.4) but it will work on earlier versions if you swap that to `array()`.

Comment: Thnx for the answers ^_^ But i get Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_set() !!

Comment: And one more thing i want to ask you guys !! how can I display random json array (model ,door, colour) to (door,model, colour) ....ect

Comment: Great, glad it is working! A note worth making though - please don't assume everyone here is a "dude" - my nickname does not carry any connotations of gender `:-)`. Since this works for you, I will make a suggestion on adding randomness if you accept the answer.

Comment: Not stupid, no - see the `:-)` I wrote. I think it's worth trying to encourage people not to assume that programmers are always male. Anyway, I am pleased this works for you - good luck with your project!